# Multisite subdirectory root not accessible

Tags: multisite, iis

I have installed WordPress Multisite on sub directory, I can access the dashboard of main and sub directory site but I get 403 Forbidden error when I try to access sub directory:

http://ibsdigitalgroup.com.au/digitalstore/

However, Below page is accessible of the same sub directory.

http://ibsdigitalgroup.com.au/digitalstore/sample-page

Here is the code for web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="wp-includes/ms-files.php?file={R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}wp-admin/" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule 7" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What kind of web server is this? IIS, nginx, ...?

Comment: windows server, Go Daddy hosting

Comment: I'm still facing this issue can anyone help me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not nearly familiar enough with IIS to offer assistance. [Googling `wordpress multisite iis 403`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=wordpress+multisite+iis+403) led me to [this post](http://blog.leederbyshire.com/2012/10/12/solved-iiswordpress-permalinks-error-403-forbidden-access-is-denied/). I don't know if this is the issue you're running into, but maybe it'll start you down the right path.